# SortedDictionary duplicate keys?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Okai, i have the following method:

```
public void Insert(SortedDictionary<byte[], uint> recs)
{
    SortedDictionary<byte[], uint> records = new SortedDictionary(recs, myComparer);
}
```

What I am hoping to achieve is to sort the records in "recs" with a new rule specified by "myComparer" which implements IComparer. It pretty much does so, but I get hit by an exception with the following message:

> An entry with the same key already
>   exists.

I am wondering how this is possible since "recs" is already a dictionary with about 130k keys.

---

```
    public int Compare(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        return  Inhouse.ByteConverter.ToString(a).CompareTo(  
                    Inhouse.ByteConverter.ToString(b));
    }
```

(it's just a snipette..)

Comment: Isn't the return type `SortedDictionary<byte[], uint>` instead of `SortedDictionary<byte[], recs>` ?

Comment: You should post the code of your Comparer, otherwise we can't help you so much...

Comment: I added a code sample for the Comparer

Comment: your comparer seems ok to me. Now the question is, what is the comparer used in the sortedDictionary given as parameter ? Because your comparer finds some keys equal, while the other one doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "recs" has a different comparer than the one you inject into records you may get duplicates; that is if "recs" compares by object reference and myComparer compares the actual bytes, you will have collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the comparer code:

> *Every key in a SortedDictionary(Of
>   TKey, TValue) must be unique according
>   to the specified comparer; therefore, every key in the source dictionary must also be 
>   unique according to the specified comparer.*

with your new comparer, 2 different keys with normal `byte[]` comparaison may become equal.

It's what msdn [says...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bk18b2y0.aspx)

Comment: Interesting fact but I still don't quite understand why that happens. Does the Comparer alter the keys somehow ?

Comment: No, the new dictionary will sort the keys with your comparer, but if it finds 2 keys that are equal with that comparer, it will complain. It's the same situation when you try to add the same key more than once in a dictionary (same key in this case is defined by the default comparer, and in your case by your custom comparer).

Comment: search in your original dictionary for keys `a` & `b` where `a != b` and `Inhouse.ByteConverter.ToString(a).CompareTo(Inhouse.ByteConverter.ToString(b)) == 0`

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the same `Dictionary` object in the calling method. So I imagine your code is something like this:

```
 SortedDictionary<byte[], uint> dic = new SortedDictionary<byte[], uint>();
 foreach (var thing in things)
 {
     dic.Clear();
     Populate(dic);
     Insert(dic);
 }
```

Where it should be like this:

```
SortedDictionary<byte[], uint> dic = new SortedDictionary<byte[], uint>();
foreach (var thing in things)
{
    dic = new SortedDictionary<byte[], uint>();
    Populate(dic);
    Insert(dic);
}
```

Can you post the code that is calling your `Insert` method?

Comment: I don't quite have access to the calling scope.